# Encapsulation and input validation duplication

Tags: c#, object-oriented, object-oriented-design, refactoring, orm

Consider the following example (very simplified):

```
public class Basket
{
    private readonly List<BasketItem> _items = new List<BasketItem>();
    public IReadOnlyCollection<BasketItem> Items => _items;

    // _items.Sum(item=>item.TotalAmount)
    public decimal TotalAmount { get; private set; } 
    // ...other properties ...

    public void ChangeItemQuantity(BasketItem item, decimal quantity)
    {
        if (item == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(item));
        ///////////////////////////////////
        // code duplication
        if (quantity <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(quantity));
        ///////////////////////////////////

        item.ChangeQuantity(quantity);

        // recalculates basket totals, items.Sum(item=>item.TotalAmount)
        RecalculateTotals();  
    }
}

public class BasketItem
{
    public decimal Quantity { get; private set; }
    public decimal TotalAmount { get; private set; } // quantity * price
    // ...other properties ...

    public void ChangeQuantity(decimal quantity)
    {
        ///////////////////////////////////
        // code duplication
        if (quantity <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(quantity));
        ///////////////////////////////////

        Quantity = quantity;

        RecalculateTotals(); // recalculates item total (price * quantity)
    }
}
```

As you can see I encapsulate things a lot (I'm really considering moving away from OOP).

The problem I see with this code is that I perform the same validation in 2 places. It's actually the same validation in 3 places because there's additional one at the boundaries (API/UI layer).

Could you tell me please, is the validation in `Basket.ChangeItemQuantity` redundant?

Comment: Your problem is that Item should not have quantity, nor should item recalculate totals.

Comment: @Bent but it's a `BasketItem` actually, and `BasketItem` has a `Product` inside

Comment: It is made that way because it is stored that way in the database. Each basket item is stored separately in the relational database (separate table for items). Maybe relational database might not be the best DB to store basket...

Comment: "*As you can see I encapsulate things a lot*". I'd dispute this. The code inside your `BasketItem.ChangeQuantity` could sit inside `Quantity`'s setter and all you are "encapsulating" is the `null` and value checks.

Comment: @DavidArno I'm encapsulating it because changing quantity has a side-effect and mutates other fields too. It could sit in a setter but it wouldn't change too much IMO.

Comment: I'm curious about the using code. Why, if I have a reference to a `BasketItem` do I tell the `Basket` to change the quantity rather then just telling the `BasketItem` directly? How is the `Basket` helping at all here?

Comment: @candied_orange because changing `Quantity` in `BasketItem` invalidates the total amount in the `Basket` and it must be recalculated, or invalidated and calculated on the next access, so the quantity should and must only be changed from the `Basket` class. I could, of course, use computed property but I need to persist those total amounts in my DB, so again my ORM is limiting me regarding the design and I don't really want to have 2 different models for data and logic, that's more code to manage and I already have to manage 2 different models (API, data)

Comment: What exactly does `RecalculateTotals()` do? It doesn't return anything so it must be talking to something.

Comment: `RecalculateTotals` just mutates the fields/private setter property, `public decimal TotalAmount { get; private set; }`. It sums totals of all the items in the basket basically.

Comment: If quantity must only be changed from `Basket` you are failing to encapsulate by letting others have access to `BasketItem` and `BasketItem.ChangeQuantity()`

Comment: @candied_orange there are no friend classes in C#, so I don't see another way here, I guess encapsulation can't be easily applied to data (orm) models. But you're damn right, my encapsulation sucks.

Comment: There are other ways. What if `Basket.ChangeItemQuantity(basketItem, quantity)` was `Basket.ChangeItemQuantity(rowNumber, quantity)`?

Comment: The problem is, I retrieve the basket items from my DB outside my models(repositories/services/controllers/handlers) individually, and I already have a reference to the `BasketItem` there, I don't really have a `rowNumber` to pass to the basket. And I'm still failing to encapsulate because everyone can change the quantity of a basket item, I think it's unfixable unless I'll move the quantity to the `Basket` class itself but then it's more work to manage separate business models and map them to data models just to persist them. It would be much easier to solve with document DB like mongo

Comment: Hmm, I think this is starting to sound like the age vs birthday problem. It's a bad idea to store a person's age in a DB at all because who wants to recalculate everyones age every day just because someone might have had a birthday. Just store their birthdate and do the math when someone asks for age.

Comment: Similarly, you might want to just not store totals in the DB but calculate them when needed. Of course once you check out they need to be recorded but at that time quantity is fixed. Now were recording an event that took place at a time. Nothing needs to change so totals stop being volatile.

Comment: Done this way you don't care who changed what when. You calculate totals when something asks for them. All you need is to be able to traverse whatever your totaling.

Comment: @candied_orange you're right, I think my problem is more like trying to use data model(orm) as my business(domain) model and because of that, I must wrap my business logic around my data model (make it fit to be compliant with the database structure). I think it would be much better to have 2 separate models in this case, or don't use encapsulation and OOP here at all and handle all the logic separately in some class...

Comment: Or do as you say, and use computed properties, and have some separate database made just for reports (reporting database,data warehouse). Thanks for the help, I must seriously think about some better design/solution to this problem.

Comment: That sounds good. I like to have a single source of truth. Keeps the data from conflicting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Could you tell me please, is the validation in Basket.ChangeItemQuantity redundant?

Yes it's redundant. But that's the least of your problems.

Semantically it's weird for an Item to know how many of it are in a basket. It's weird of it to know it's even in a basket. This reads like I could ask a potato to total up my order. Your items simply know to much.

Maybe I'm reading to much into the names and what you really want to know is if having multiple levels of validation of the same thing is always bad. It's not. Provided it's happening at the right places.

When you're crossing significant boundaries validation is a good idea. When you're taking in user data you're at a big one. When building persisting data structures is another. It's OK to put validation of the same thing on the doors through these walls.  It maybe redundant but it helps me read your code. I know right away what your expectations are without having to dig around in other places to know what's allowed.

In fact, whenever talking to, or listening to anything that doesn't fully enforce your model on it's own, you should consider validating to impose your model on it.

Maintaining duplicate code is still annoying. Make peace with the fact that identical code, doing a different job, that could change for a different reason, has a perfectly good reason to exist.

That said, it may be you're dealing with a case of [primitive obsession](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrimitiveObsession). You keep using `decimal` when what you seem to want is a positive quantity. You could stop spreading `decimal` and it's validation code around by sticking both of them in a `Quantity` class. Now all you have to check for is `null`. Sigh.

Comment: "*Now all you have to check for is `null`. Sigh*". For a few months more only. C# 8's nullable reference types will neatly address this issue.

Comment: "Semantically it's weird for an Item to know how many of it are in a basket." it might be, but as I said before the `BasketItem` is a separate table in the database. And quantity is a column. So my database is designed this way. I could store the quantity in some kind of `Dictionary` or something, inside my `Basket` class but then it wouldn't map to my database table and I would need a separate data models and business models and manage mappings between them. That's why I use the data model as a business model (2 in 1) and just map to my view model (API model).

Comment: Because `Quantity` is a column in `BasketItems` table in my RDBMS. To apply your suggestion I would have to add another model (layer) on top of my data model or don't use RDBMS at all, or use document db and store serialized basket directly (in form of some JSON or something).

Comment: Because otherwise, how would you store a basket (or shopping cart) with it's items in the relational database?

Comment: You seem to be very focused on your DB. So much so that you've created a class named after a join table and expected people to somehow just know what you meant. I didn't. I doubt others will either.

Comment: @candied_orange Yeah. I'm sorry but I forgot to mention I'm using ORM and these models represent my database tables and that's why I modelled them this way. Otherwise, I'd just put the quantity in my `Basket` directly..

Comment: `it's weird for Item to know how many of it are in a basket` what if the object's functionality depends on knowing this?

Comment: @coolpasta some functionality doesn't belong in some objects.

Comment: @DavidArno c# 8's nullable reference types look very cool. Compiler enforced null checks right in the type system. So much better than annotations. Wonder how long it will take Java to do this.

Comment: @candied_orange there’s a saying, “if you want to know what Java will look like in five years’ time, look at C# now”. There’s a high degree of poetic licence and a degree of micky taking in that phrase. But there’s some element of truth there too. ;)

Comment: @DavidArno wish they'd picked a better name. Googling for info on this turns up so many false positives.  Kotlin seems to have led the way here.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the redundant code is a bigger problem. Why does your Basket-Class has a method "ChangeItemQuantity" when the item you pass as an argument to it has this exact same method with the same business-logic? To be clear, a method name which occurs multiple times may not be a problem, but business-logic code which occurs multiple times is definitely one. Thats redundant code which has to be maintained. Another question is, where is your method "RecalculateTotals" located? Is it redundant, too?

But that was not the question, maybe your code all in all makes more sense than this excerpt.

Im terms of validation, to be pedantic you have to validate a specific value / input at every place where you can't guarantee that it has been validated before. In your example, the method "ChangeQuantity" of your BasketItem could be called directly from client-code without going through the method "ChangeQuantity" of your Basket. So you have to assume that the input parameters of the BasketItem-method are not validated yet.

If BasketItem would be a private class inside the public Basket class and the only execution-path to BasketItem.ChangeQuantity() gous through Basket.ChangeQuantity() where the data is validated, I would say it's not necessary to validate it again, because you can be sure that it was validated before. But evan in that case one could argue that maybe in a later refactoring, the private class may be moved outside and become public.

To be clear, thats a really pedantic view which can't be followed the whole time. In addition, all this validation-code is pretty bloating and makes the actual porpuse of the method more unreadable. All I want to say is, assumptions about other modules / classes from the current module / class are often a bad thing in object oriented software and should be made whisely, because you can never be sure that the assumption turns out wrong (now or maybe in the future).

Comment: "I would say that the redundant code is a bigger problem. Why does your Basket-Class has a method "ChangeItemQuantity" when the item you pass as an argument to it has this exact same method with the same business-logic?" 
 - Because changing quantity of some item in the basket changes total amount in the basket, so it invalidates state of the basket

Comment: @Konrad That reasoning is correct, but this also means that a `BasketItem` should not have a publicly available `ChangeQuantity()` method – someone _could_ call that directly and therefore invalidate the `Basket` state.